# Setting Up Xampp and Saving Files For Php

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I am brand new to php and having some trouble running php code locally for testing. I have set up lampp locally on my machine (running ubuntu) and I have put the a .php file in the folder. Whenever I try to edit and save the file gedit says I don't have the correct permissions. I tried running `chmod 777` on the folder but it says I don't have the necessary permissions. (This seems like a bad idea either way)

Basically what I am wondering is where I should put the php files to be hosted by xampp (or lampp). I would rather store them in a git repository I have setup in another directory but I am not sure how to run them from chrome and locally host the php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which folder did you exactly store the .php file?
And did you use 'sudo chmod 777' or just 'chmod 777'
Please confirm the above before I can actually clear your doubt.

Comment: I think it was a problem with not including sudo and trying to apply it to the folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed xampp (if you are running windows) it will be in C:\Xampp, if you want to run a php file, you will need to place it in a folder called 'htdocs' located in C:\Xampp\htdocs. As an example, create a file called "test.php" and save it in C:\xampp\htdocs.
Put this as the contents of the php file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!"
?>
```

Once you have the file saved in your htdocs folder, you will need to open the xampp control panel, it's located in the xampp directory and called xampp-control.exe. Once that is open, you will need to start "Apache service" and if you want "mysql service". Once they are both started successfully head over to your browser and navigate to localhost/test.php and it should echo "Hello World". I hope this has helped you and you have fun experimenting with php.